# 3 summations in 1 constraints on CPLEX

Tags: cplex

how to model something like forall the sum of (x) sum of (y) sum of (z) dvar(x;y;z)==1

I made this but it doesn't work:

forall (t in T) sum(o in O) sum(w in W) sum(h in H) x[t,o,w,h]==1;

Cplex said: unexpected forall ?

thank you

Comment: Did you fix this yet? The tiny snippet you give looks OK, so if you need more help, we would need to see more of the context, such as teh declarations of the sets and variables, and what doe the preceding lines before this snippet look like?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a constraint. It should be something like this :
subject to :
{
forall (t in T)
Constraint_Name:
  sum (o in O, w in W, h in H) X[t][o][w][h] == 1;
}
look for "cplex tutorial" on google there are also tutorials on IBM website.